# Using a private go module on Gitlab as import : "Unknown revision"

Tags: go, gitlab-ci, go-modules

I cannot get this to work, even after checking other topics on stackoverflow. My project on `gitlab.com/my_company/backend` needs a module, found at `gitlab.com/my_company/pkg/auth`.
Locally, I've setup `GOPRIVATE` / git's configuration to make it work (and it works), though in Gitlab's CI Pipelines on a merge request, this fails.

##### Pipeline log / go.mod

I've added some debugging logs just to make sure everything was setup like I thought. Here's a failing pipeline's log :

```
$ git config --global url."ssh://git@gitlab.com/my_company/".insteadOf "https://gitlab.com/my_company/"
$ git config --global url."git@gitlab.com:".insteadOf "https://gitlab.com/"
$ git config -l | grep instead
url.ssh://git@gitlab.com/my_company/.insteadof=https://gitlab.com/my_company/
url.git@gitlab.com:.insteadof=https://gitlab.com/

$ env | grep GOPRIVATE
GOPRIVATE=gitlab.com/my_company

$ go mod download
go: gitlab.com/my_company/pkg/auth@v1.1.0: reading gitlab.com/my_company/pkg/auth/auth/go.mod at revision auth/v1.1.0: unknown revision auth/v1.1.0
```

One weird part of this log I've found is :
`reading gitlab.com/my_company/pkg/auth/auth/go.mod` - why is it repeating auth/auth? It actually happened once before locally, but it was because I wrote "github" instead of "gitlab" :)

The relevant go.mod line just in case :

```
require (
    gitlab.com/my_company/pkg/auth v1.1.0 // indirect
)
```

##### Repository tags

Here are the tags setup on the repository `gitlab.com/my_company/pkg` :

```
$ git tag -l
auth/v1.0.0
auth/v1.1.0
cache/v1.0.0
cache/v1.0.1

$ git ls-remote --tags
From git@gitlab.my_company/pkg.git
9efcb02d5489adaac9d525dcb496d868d65e856a    refs/tags/auth/v1.0.0
13730d4f61df978c6d690fd2678e2ed924808e0c    refs/tags/auth/v1.1.0
2b8dff0ec1b737d975290720933180a9b591a1db    refs/tags/cache/v1.0.0
9a3e598bbf83bea57b29d8a908b514861ae37b12    refs/tags/cache/v1.0.1
```

I'm not that familiar with Gitlab CI so I'm out of things to try. Any ideas?

Thank you!

---

Update: I finally got gitlab-runner installed so I could try running the yml directly, no luck. It still works locally (not a big surprise).

Comment: > why is it repeating `auth/auth`?
That suggests that the [`go-import` metadata](https://golang.org/ref/mod#vcs-find) being returned to the CI server may be incorrect. Perhaps you need to set up the CI server with a `.netrc` file with HTTPS credentials in order to get the correct metadata?

Answer (score 0):

In you project should be file `.gitlab-ci.yml` and you can add `GOPRIVATE` variable to your CI and runner will use it for you project.

More details how to add env vars:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#create-a-custom-cicd-variable-in-the-gitlab-ciyml-file

Comment: As specified in my post, GOPRIVATE is already set : `GOPRIVATE=gitlab.com/my_company`. Works locally, doesn't work on gitlab. Tried various values, with/without wildcards, it doesn't change the result.

Comment: @NathanaelC. sorry, skipped info that printing was from runner. 
1. Do you have the same version of go in runner and local?
2. Have you logged in your docker to gitlab with auth-token? https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/